# Bootstrap tooltip cut in end of carousel image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap carousel, inside it there's an image, and this image has a tooltip which is cut by the edge of the carousel image left corner.

[Tooltip cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSGC4.png)

The tooltip text and bubble is cut in the white of my carousel image.

My code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
<div class="image-cropper">
<img data-src="<?=$match[$i]->champImage?>" class="img img-rounded centered"
 alt="<?=$match[$i]->champName?>" style="margin-right:10px;"/>
 </div>
<div class="carousel-leftCaption">
            <img class="img-circle" src="<?=$lol->itemImage($match[$i]->item1['itemId'])?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$match[$i]->item1['name']?>
            <?=$match[$i]->item1['description']?>">
            <img class="img-circle" src="<?=$lol->itemImage($match[$i]->item2['itemId'])?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$match[$i]->item2['name']?>">
            <img class="img-circle" src="<?=$lol->itemImage($match[$i]->item3['itemId'])?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$match[$i]->item3['name']?>"><br/>
            <img class="img-circle" src="<?=$lol->itemImage($match[$i]->item4['itemId'])?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$match[$i]->item4['name']?>">
            <img class="img-circle" src="<?=$lol->itemImage($match[$i]->item5['itemId'])?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$match[$i]->item5['name']?>">
            <img class="img-circle" src="<?=$lol->itemImage($match[$i]->item6['itemId'])?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$match[$i]->item6['name']?>">
           </div>
```

There is any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of built-in css rule:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

You can add these css:

```
.carousel-inner {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

...but it will make all slides visible so you can't manage it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default Bootatrap has `overflow: hidden` on `carousel-inner` class to prevent showing other images while sliding.

I think you can do two things:

Add this to CSS (after Bootstrap styles):

```
.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
}
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add this jQuery code (to prevent showing other images during sliding):

```
$('#yourCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  $(this).find('.carousel-inner').addClass('overflow-hidden');
});

$('#yourCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $(this).find('.carousel-inner').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
})
```